# How can i get c:out value in Controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

===============================update====================================

```
try{
    // snip

    while (rs.next()) {
        BookListEntity entity = new BookListEntity();
        entity.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        entity.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        entity.setSubject(rs.getString("subject"));
        entity.setInsertTime(rs.getString("insert_time"));
        entity.setRentalCheck(rs.getInt("rental_check"));

        BookList.add(entity);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

model.addAttribute("TestList",BookList);
```

this is first controller
-> get BookList to "TestList" and move to view(jsp)

```
<c:forEach var="listValue" items="${TestList}">
    <form action="rentalandreturn.do" method="post">
        <tr class="active">
            <td><c:out value="${listValue.id}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${listValue.name}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${listValue.subject}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${listValue.insertTime}" /></td>
            <c:if test="${listValue.rentalCheck eq 1}">
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="貸し出しする" />
                </td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${listValue.rentalCheck eq 0}">
                <td><input type="submit" value="返納する" /></td>
            </c:if>
        </tr>
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

This is jsp(view) code
->and I want to use c:out value something do

```
@Controller
public class Rentalandreturn {

    @RequestMapping(value = "rentalandreturn", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String rentalandreturn(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        //How can i get c:out value?
        String id = (String) request.getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println(id);
        return "BookList";
    }
}
```

and this is second java code(Controller)
-> I want to get c:out value what I print view page.

is there any way to get c:out value in Controller(=java code)?

sorry about my English. if you don't understand my question. say to comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--you *have* the values in the controller, it's the list you're sending to the view layer. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Read up on a simple case of `POST`ing data to a servlet.  The values that you want to POST should be form fields

Comment: If you use a a web browser dev tools (inspect) you will see that the `c:out` is just normal text.  As I said before, they will need to be `form` fields (even hidden) to be POSTED back to the servlet

Comment: Scary Wombat    Thank you for your comment!
I using hidden type to sending my value. thank you for Reminding to me different just text and form-input.

Comment: From `Controller` and `RequestMapping`, I assume that you are using SpringMVC. Don't try to invent an oval wheel when round ones are available around and try to mimic examples from the Spring doc or from a SpringMVC tutorial. SpringMVC contains magic to easily read form input fields from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can not read  directly in controller class as it is in , better to write a javascript code to to read the data and from that on an action you can send to controller.

Comment: Please do not give so terrible advices. Controller are meant to extract values from requests and pass data to responses...

Comment: Yes you are right but his question is not about request, request will come to controller from some action and that action will bind the view with controller, you seems taken otherwise.

Comment: The `@RequestMapping` annotated method is meant to receive the request submitted by that form `<form action="rentalandreturn.do" method="post">`. Ok there are some imprecisions in OP's code but that's the way I understand that.